# How many surjective functions can there be for this condition?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a set of numbers such that

$N_z = \{1, 2, .., z\} $

and a general function as:

$f : N_{10} \longrightarrow N_4$

The condition which has to be met is that "each inverse image $x$, has to have exactly $x \in N_4$ inverse
images"

**My thought was:**

The cardinality of both sets for a surjective function is correct: $\operatorname{card}(A)>\operatorname{card}(B)$ as $N_{10} > N_4$
and the count of surjective functions that follow the condition goes as:

$VR(4, 10) = 4^{10} = 1048576$; $4$ elements combined $10$ times

**Is this number correct?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The inverse images of the elements of $N_4$ partition $N_{10}$ into $4$ sets of sizes $1$, $2$, $3$ and $4$. So such a function $f$ chooses $1$ element to map to $1$, and $2$ elements to map to $2$, etc.

Comment: So there can't be any since there are more elements to map than the ones we have?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The inverse images together should have $1+2+3+4=10$ elements, which is precisely the right amount.

Comment: I meant, there are no suryective functions that satisfy f : N10 -> N4 (still learning LaTex, can't find the one I wanted)